# SAS proc import column name has dollar sign $

Tags: import, sas, dollar-sign

I am importing a file with column headers include a $ sign (e.g. "Sales $") with proc import. The result of the import seems to rename that column something like "VAR11".

```
proc import out = raw
    datafile="example.xlsx" 
    dbms=xlsx replace;
    range = "Sheet1$A1:B50";
    getnames = yes;
run;
```

Is there a way to still read in the name of the column, but just drop the $ sign so it is a meaningful header?

Comment: Try this: `option VALIDVARNAME=ANY;` before import

Comment: if it is just one column you can rename by using out =raw(rename=(var11=newvar))

Comment: Unfortunately, @Kiran, this type of var names appears like 50 times so it would be hard to rename one by one. Thanks for the thought!

Comment: @pinegulf, this works! I will just need to refer to the var name as such `'Sales $'n` (see, SAS Name Literals)

Comment: I would suggest you not do that. The labels are still there with the dollar sign but typing out the variable name with quotes and $ is going to get boring really fast. You can use the labels for reports and presentations instead of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem names are in that format then you should be able to read it and then rename the variable using the label.  So get the names and labels into a dataset.  You can query dictionary tables, use proc contents, or you could use PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc transpose data=raw (obs=0) out=names ;
  var _all_ ;
run;
```

Now make a list of oldname=newname pairs into a macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select catx('=',_name_,translate(trim(compress(_label_,'$')),'_',' '))
    into :renames separated by ' '
  from names
  where upcase(_name_) ne upcase(substrn(_label_,1,32))
  ;
quit;
```

You can then use that in a RENAME statement or RENAME= dataset option.

```
data renamed;
  set raw(rename=(&renames)) ;
run;
```

Comment: That is a good way. But I have tried your code with a variable name containing more than one "_", it remove only one of them. Like a label = "Name $ good" become "Name__good"

Comment: You can add a call to `compbl()` before call to `translate()` so that multiple spaces are reduced to a single space.

Comment: Sorry, but they are not the spaces that are repeated, but the sign "_" which is repeated one two times. for example, if the variable name is Name_____good, how to modify it to Name_good?

Comment: @D.O. So the name started as `Name_$_good` and not `Name $ good` as you originally stated? If so then you will need a more complex logic to replace the multiple underscore.  Regular expressions could do it.  Replacing underscores with spaces, using compbl(), and then translating the spaces back to underscores would also work.